# Create HTML link which opens in a new tab/window with a completely fresh context

Tags: hyperlink, click

Is it possible to create a HTML link which opens in a new browser window/tab with a completely fresh context, meaning by clicking the link it should just open a new window/tab without the context of the previous page and especially *without copying the session storage* of the previous page into the new page. It should just load the page provided in the `href="..."` attribute, as if the user opened an new browser window/tab and then loaded a specific web url.

First I just tried using `(1)`:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Then I tried `(2)`:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Google</a>
```

and `(3)`:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Google</a>
```

as well as `(4)`:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Google</a>
```

but `(1)` did not work as expected. `(2)`, `(3)` and `(4)` only worked with Firefox 65.0, but not with Chromium 71.0 and Chrome 72.0, where in Chromium/Chrome the same session storage gets used as of the page where the clicked link was embedded.

I am referring to this question:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203918/html-link-with-noopener-and-or-noreferrer-in-chrome-chromium-results-in-unex

I am not requiring using the `rel` attribute. I am looking for any possibility to achieve the intended behaviour for a majority of browsers.